# How to connect an android application to remote database server in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, mysql, sqlite, xamarin-studio

I am creating a android application in Xamarin Studio, The app should send and receive data from remote database.

**References:**

I found references to connect to local database in cross platform. 
[Create Database with ADO.NET and SQLite.NET](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/data/sqlite/)

I also found out that the remote database can be connected with the help of web service.
[To Consume Web Service](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/)

I cannot able to find a direct example or an idea on how to connect to remote database?

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

A common way to perform this is using a REST service. This does require you to have a service layer between your app and the database but this also helps ensure a few things:

- Provides an abstraction layer between your app and the data
- Allow ability to implement OAuth or other security layering if needed without impacting your design too much
- Ensures a common interface to the data layer if you need to go to iphone also or other UX areas.
- Helps ensure there is minimal amount of bits coming to the app (if it can be helped, an app shouldn't eat up a persons data plan)

SERVER: I would suggest either something like [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) for the REST Service or use a cloud service if you already have that going for other things.

There is an AZURE Mobile service [Xamarin Component](http://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-mobile-services) in the Component Store

CLIENT: Here is and [example](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/) of the app code to call the REST Service

Comment: Your links were helpful, The Web hosting servers also provide for access for database storage, which are normally used for websites. But if I want to connect to such database, do I require an API ?